# Convert double to exaclty two decimal place in java

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I want to convert a dobule to exaclty two places.I have answers to lhe same query but none of them satisfies for my problem.

This is the code i am using :

```
Double d=15.99965754;
System.out.println("Value before formatting is : "+d);
String value=new DecimalFormat("##.00").format(d);
System.out.println("The value after formatting is :" +Double.parseDouble(value));
```

And the output i am getting is

**Value before formatting is : 15.99965754
The value after formatting is :16.0**

but what i actually looking forward to print is :

**Value before formatting is : 15.99965754
The value after formatting is :16.00**

No matter what the double value is i should get the decimal to exactly two places.

Comment: Why are you using `Double.parseDouble` at the end, if you care about the format that the `Double` appears in? `parseDouble` returns a `double`, not a `String`.

Comment: The final value i need is in double,that's the reason i am converting it.

Comment: A `double` is a type of number.  That means that `(double) 16`, `(double) 16.0` and `(double) 16.00` are all exactly the same.  If you want to see a particular number of zeroes, then what you need is a `String`.

Comment: This is only a test code..In my main program i am adding this value(double value) to a VO.I can only add a dobule value to it,but again i want exactly two deciaml places.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are doing with it.  There is only one `double` whose value is 16.  It doesn't make sense to talk about "wanting 16.00 instead of 16.0" - they are all the same `double`.

Comment: Yup you are right,but my requirement is the display should be with exactly 2 decimal places at the same time i cannot change the type to anything else than double.So are you saying that it's not possible to print with exaclty 2 decimal digits with the data format being double?

Comment: Printing doubles with a pre-determined number of decimal places is what `DecimalFormat` is for.  You've already shown that you know how to use this.

Answer (score 7):

Do not parse value, just print

```
System.out.println("The value after formatting is :" + value);
```

another way to get the same resut

```
System.out.printf("The value after formatting is : %.2f", d);
```

Comment: but the requirement is that the final value should be in double.

Comment: requirement seems to be wrong, double cannot have precision, we can only format it with different number of digits after decimal point. BigDecimal has precision